# Geocode and Parse Addresses problem

Tags: geocoding

I have the following error when I attempt to execute the geocode operation in civiCRM 4.7.31 on D7:

> Entity: Job Action: geocode Summary Finished execution of Geocode and
>   Parse Addresses with result: Failure, Error message: Aborting batch
>   geocoding. Hit the over query limit on geocoder. Details
>
> Parameters raw (from db settings):  geocoding=1 parse=0 start=1
>   end=100 throttle=1
>
> Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
>   a:6:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:9:"geocoding";s:1:"1";s:5:"parse";s:1:"0";s:5:"start";s:1:"1";s:3:"end";s:3:"100";s:8:"throttle";s:1:"1";}
>
> Full message:  Finished execution of Geocode and Parse Addresses with
>   result: Failure, Error message: Aborting batch geocoding. Hit the over
>   query limit on geocoder.

I've entered my Google API map provider key in Settings - Mapping and Geocoding Providers. I've selected Google on the pull-down menus for Mapping and Geocoding Provider. I didn't think 100 records were too many to geocode.

In the **Name (Frequency)/Description** column, I have the following:
Geocode and Parse Addresses (Daily)
Retrieves geocodes (lat and long) and / or parses street addresses (populates street number, street name, etc.)
API Entity: Job
API Action: geocode

Any suggestions of changes in my settings?

Answer (score 1):

The limits are listed here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

It looks like you've set throttling so it probably isn't a queries-per-second problem.

You can log into your developer console at google to see how much you actually are using. I'd start there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of geocoding going on in CiviCRM. Geocoding can be activated when contacts w/ addresses are imported; we’ve also hit geocoding limits issuing TaxReceipts (for which we had to retrieve addresses from the database); we have clients unexpectedly run into geocoding limits - a common factor has been ‘we were exporting data’ - though we have not gotten to the bottom of it yet.